# SQL Query to select between NULL

Tags: mysql

I need to select rows which are between the two null values.

My Question is that how can i get the names and marks of selected class which i need. I can't change table everytime, because total number of rows in table is about 13000.

I think it's too much and even more i am getting this table from excel file with some changes every time(twice a day or even more). What will be your opinion?

for example:-

```
Name       Marks
=================
class10    NULL
rahul      45
priti      65
terry      74
class9     NULL
Andrew     80
Nastya     75
Ajay       81
class8     NULL!
```

Comment: i would suggest you make better table structure. you can keep the student_marks table having columns student_name, class, marks

Comment: I agree with @DhairyaVora, this is a case of bad database design. You should improve it. Migrating your data would be easy too.

Comment: actualy i am getting this from an excel file and it's too big. Is there any option except chaning the table structure. i can't get the excel file in any other changed form.

Comment: what are you using for reading excel and inserting data to database? php/javascript/something else?

Comment: what would you do in this case? The main problem is that client can provide you excel file only in this way. There are about 13000 rows in that excel file in the same way as i have marked above. i need to populate them seperatly. Any suggestions.....

Comment: i am using php function to import this file @Dhairya

Comment: so, you need to modify php code to implement required logic such that it reads excel sheet and generates the insert query the way @migg has showed you.

Comment: the question seems to be meaning less , why r u using a NULL as a value separator , do tell us ur prev prob so that we can help creating ur table precisely , this is not the correct way to separate values

Comment: i had no options except comparing with null as i had such file imported from excel.@Hussian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table has the wrong layout to serve your needs. There is no way to select rows "between values" in SQL, only if your table had an additional index that defines the order of the rows.

The correct table layout would be like this:

```
Class      Name       Marks
class10    rahul      45
class10    priti      65
class10    terry      74
class9     Andrew     80
class9     Nastya     75
class9     Ajay       81
...
```

Then you could query all members of class10 like this:

```
SELECT Name, Marks FROM table WHERE Class = 'class10'
```

Even better would be to make your own table for classes, but i doubt in your case of Excel-Import this would be desirable.

Hope this helps.

EDIT: Then import your excel table with an index so that it looks like this:

```
ID   Name       Marks
=====================
1    class10    NULL
2    rahul      45
3    priti      65
4    terry      74
5    class9     NULL
6    Andrew     80
7    Nastya     75
8    Ajay       81
9    class8     NULL!
```

Then you can select your marks of your class 10 like:

```
SELECT Name, Marks FROM table WHERE ID BETWEEN 2 AND 4
```

Or your class 9 like:

```
SELECT Name, Marks FROM table WHERE ID BETWEEN 6 AND 8
```

With a scripting language like PHP you could automate this task in a script.

Comment: Thank you @migg and vinod for your quick answers but i can't change the excel file that's the main problem and changing everytime (twice a day) this table, i think is not a good practice. Any other options.....

Comment: If you would like to automate e.g. in PHP then this query would select the names and IDs of all classes: `SELECT ID, Name AS Class FROM table WHERE Marks IS NULL`. This in combination with a loop would be enough to output all students and marks with their associated classes.

Comment: Thanks again @migg.I have some doubt about importing excel file with index.....but hope i should solve it myself. If not then i will knock here again....Thanks a lot all of you for your great support and quick responce.

Comment: If you import the data into an existing table with a column ID that is a primary key and has the auto_increment property, this would be done automatically. Otherwise you could add the index column afterwards as primary key with auto_increment for the same result.

Comment: I did it! Thanks a lot @migg and everyone for ur support.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean that you want records without nulls then use -

```
select * from table_name where marks is not null
```

Comment: ya that is @parag. but i need names and marks for each class not all at the same time..

Answer (score -1):

By "in-between nulls" do you mean those without null values?

If so, you can do this:

```
select * from classTable where NOT ISNULL(Marks);
```

Edit:
The data format in your excel sheet is very bad. The class name should be another column in the table. 
Right now, if you take a row with data `Name:Rahul, Marks:70`, no part of this row indicates what class the student is in. You are depending solely on the data order to determine class - this design is very unreliable.

So my recommendation is to include another column in the excel sheet, and consequently in the MySql table.